# FancyBox: open new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, modal-dialog

I have a very simple webpage called a.html where I want to click on an image and I want a modal window to be opened, loading the content from b.html#main instead of from the main div from the a.html webpage.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you readout the documentation of fancy box ? .. off-course you did not ... you can easily find it under the head of "Create a link element (<a href>)" in ajax portion . {http://fancybox.net/howto}

Comment: Well I did, but as in the ajax part there is a .php link, and I am not using that, so I didn't keep looking at it; I just want it to open a modal window with the info contained in b.html#main

Comment: you can use b.html in href and it works. but for obtain specific id i don't think so it should b done ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "iframe" option. There's some code [here on the fancybox Howto page](http://fancybox.net/howto).

Cheers,
Al

Comment: just using a custom selector for the fancybox(), using the option 'iframe' worked! Thanks!